# Bootstrap grid make a column expand under its neighbor column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys its hard to put this in english so here is the drawing of the layout I want to accomplish. I don't know if this is possible in Bootstrap grid system only.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6" id="col1">... children </div>
   <div class="col-md-6" id="col2">... children </div>
</div>
```

[image: drawing of the layout]

Comment: row2 is a child of col2.

Comment: did you setted a particular height onto the row that makes col1 expanded?

Comment: No but its contents is pictures so it is bound to be more bigger than column2.

Comment: Not possible in TB..and never was AFAIK. HTML elements are all rectangular...certainly not L-shaped.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible with the Bootstrap grid system.
You will have to divide your first div.

Maybe the [css float property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) can do what you need ?

here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y1dj5166/

```
<p style="color: blue">
<span style="float: right; color:red;"> 
other text. other text. other text. other text.<br/>
other text. other text. other text. other text.<br/> 
other text. other text. other text. other text.<br/> 
</span>
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. 
</p>
```